# Reinstalling android open-source version

Tags: android

I am currently using a phone that was locally made in my country, Everything else is great but I don't like its extra features, it has ads and other annoying stuff

Since android is an open source code os, I was wondering If i could change the current android with the most basic open source version of the android

P.S: I want the phone to function perfectly all of the phone's features like fingerprint, sims should work flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is best-suited for a different community. Judging by the way you're asking this, you're not fully aware of the scope of this task, or the limitations that come with an AOSP build of Android. Check to see if there's a custom ROM for your phone and use that if possible. There's no guarantee the experience is the same though.

Check out [xda-developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com) for example. They have large communities for all sorts of devices.